# Таймер от 60 до 0

Tags: android

Требуеться создать таймер который считает от 60 до 0  во время счёта можно приостонавливать и возобновлять счет. + Возможность сброса.
Через что будет более менее понятно реализовать это? Если можно маленький пример)

Comment: разбейте вашу задачу на более мелкие, и решайте их отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Маленький пример специально для Вас:

### count_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#c8ffffff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:text="Таймер - 60 секунд"
    android:id="@+id/timerTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Старт"
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timerTxt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onBtnStart" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Стоп"
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onBtnStop"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### StopWatch.class

```
public class StopWatch extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView timerTxt;
CountDownTimer cd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.count_down);

    timerTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTxt);
}

public void onBtnStart (View v){
    timerTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    cd = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerTxt.setText("Осталось секунд: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerTxt.setText("Завершено");
            timerTxt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }.start();
}

public void onBtnStop(View v){
    timerTxt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    timerTxt.setText("Нажмите старт");
    cd.cancel();
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Timer и TimerTask

```
Int i = 60;
Timer timer;

void start(){
timer = new Timer();
timer.shedule(new TimerTask(){
...
If (i > 0) i--;
}, 1000, 1000);
}

void pause(){
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
}
```

Со сбросом думаю понятно, как сделать.

1000 - время в миллисекундах, после первой запятой это через сколько запустится задача, после 2-й запятой - период повторения задачи.